# Question about Euler's formula

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a question about Euler's formula

$$e^{ix} = \cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$

I want to show

$$\sin(ax)\sin(bx) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos((a-b)x)-\cos((a+b)x))$$

and

$$  \cos(ax)\cos(bx) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos((a-b)x)+\cos((a+b)x))$$

I'm not really sure how to get started here.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin { \left( ax \right)  } \sin { \left( bx \right) =\left( \frac { { e }^{ aix }-{ e }^{ -aix } }{ 2i }  \right) \left( \frac { { e }^{ bix }-{ e }^{ -bix } }{ 2i }  \right)  } =\frac { { e }^{ \left( a+b \right) ix }-e^{ \left( a-b \right) ix }-{ e }^{ \left( b-a \right) ix }+{ e }^{ -\left( a+b \right) ix } }{ -4 } \\ =-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left( \frac { { e }^{ \left( a+b \right) ix }+{ e }^{ -\left( a+b \right) ix } }{ 2 } -\frac { { e }^{ \left( a-b \right) ix }+{ e }^{ -\left( a-b \right) ix } }{ 2 }  \right) =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left( \cos { \left( a-b \right) x-\cos { \left( a+b \right) x }  }  \right)   $$

same method you can do with $\cos { \left( ax \right) \cos { \left( bx \right)  }  } $

---

**Edit:**
$$\int { \sin { \left( ax \right) \sin { \left( bx \right)  }  } dx=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { \left[ \cos { \left( a-b \right) x-\cos { \left( a+b \right) x }  }  \right] dx=\quad  }  } $$$$\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { \cos { \left( a-b \right) xdx }  } -\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { \cos { \left( a+b \right) xdx= }  } $$

now to order calculate $\int { \cos { \left( a+b \right) xdx }  } $  write 
$$t=\left( a+b \right) x\quad \Rightarrow \quad x=\frac { t }{ a+b } \quad \Rightarrow dx=\frac { 1 }{ a+b } dt\\ \int { \cos { \left( a+b \right) xdx=\frac { 1 }{ a+b } \int { \cos { \left( t \right)  } dt=\frac { 1 }{ a+b } \sin { \left( t \right) = }  } \frac { 1 }{ a+b } \sin { \left( a+b \right) x }  }  } +C\\ $$

Comment: Do you know how this result could be used to calculate the integrals
 of sin(ax)sin(bx)dx? and integral of cos(ax)cos(bx)dx?

Comment: $\int { \sin { \left( ax \right) \sin { \left( bx \right)  }  } dx=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { \left( \cos { \left( a+b \right) x-\cos { \left( a-b \right) x }  }  \right) dx=\frac { 1 }{ 2\left( a+b \right)  } \int { \cos { \left( a+b \right) xd\left( a+b \right) x }  } -\frac { 1 }{ 2\left( a-b \right)  } \int { \cos { \left( a-b \right) xd\left( a-b \right) x= }  }  }  } \\ =\frac { 1 }{ 2\left( a+b \right)  } \sin { \left( a+b \right) x-\frac { 1 }{ 2\left( a-b \right)  } \sin { \left( a-b \right) x }  } +C$

Comment: could you add the integral to your answeR? it is overflowing on my page and i cannot read all of it.

Comment: Also, it seems like you got a (a+b) factor outside the integral before integrating, where did this come from

Comment: ok,i will expand my post with integral

Comment: ok thanks! ill look for the edit

Comment: ask ,if it is not clear

Comment: Shouldnt the sin definition have an "i" in the denominator?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$$\begin{align}
\cos (x\pm y)+i\sin(x\pm y)&=e^{i(x\pm y)}\\\\
&=e^{ix}e^{\pm iy}\\\\
&=\left(\cos x+i \sin x\right)\left(\cos y\pm i \sin y\right)\\\\
&=(\cos x \cos y\mp \sin x \sin y)+i(\sin x\cos y\pm \sin y\cos x)
\end{align}$$

Comment: I'm confused on your pluses and minuses? How am I suppose to know which one applies to which? YOu have a plus/minus on everything.

Comment: The convention is to follow the upper sign consistently to get one result.  Follow the lower sign consistently to get the other result.

Comment: @JacksonHart I am happy to delete the answer if this was not useful.

Comment: Do not delete it, please ! It is a useful answer. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hello my friend! How are you?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the identity

$$\sin A \cos B  \equiv \tfrac{1}{2}\left(\sin(A + B) + \sin(A - B)\right)$$

Comment: how would this be using eulers formula?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just use Euler's equation and no trig identities (except the fact that $\sin(x),\cos(x)$ are odd/even respectively), write $\sin(x)=\frac{\exp(ix)-\exp(-ix)}{2i}$ and $\cos(x)=\frac{\exp(ix)+\exp(-ix)}{2}$ and go to town simplifying the product $\sin(ax)\sin(bx)$.

Comment: How does this specifically use exp(ix) = cos(x)+isin(x)? Sorry the methodology here isn't entirely clear to me.

Comment: @JacksonHart: Write down $\exp(ix)-\exp(-ix)$ in terms of $\sin(x),\cos(x)$ and use the fact that $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$ and $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$. This will prove the formula for $\sin(x)$. Do the same for $\cos(x)$.

Comment: I have sin(ax), not sin(x). Would that just make it exp(iax)?