# fourier transform with radial coordinate

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am wanting to find the transform of this:

$$f(r) = \frac{e^{-\alpha r}}{r}$$

where $r$ is the radial coordinate. And then I would like to find $\lim_{\alpha \to \infty}$.

I have this:

$\int_0^\infty dr \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d\theta \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi r \sin{(\theta)} \exp{(-\alpha r + ikr \cos{(\theta)})}$

but when I do the integration I get 0.

Can someone see where I went wrong?

to expand:
$2\pi\int_0^\infty dr \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d\theta  r \sin{(\theta)} \exp{(-\alpha r + ikr \cos{(\theta)})}$

then I do u-substitution

$$u=\cos{\theta}$$
$$du=-sin{\theta}$$

But after u-sub, I get 0 for the integral. Perhaps I made a mistake earlier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that the FT in 3D is

$$F(\mathbf{k}) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3 \mathbf{r} \, f(\mathbf{r}) e^{i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}} $$

Now, we have radial symmetry.  Thus, $F$ is radially symmetric and we may write

$$\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r} = k r \cos{\theta} $$

So we have

$$F(k) = 2 \pi \int_0^{\infty} dr \, r \, e^{-a r} \, \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, \sin{\theta} \, e^{i k r \cos{\theta}} $$

The inner integral is, as the OP notes, doable by subbing the sine, or just evaluating as follows:

$$\int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, \sin{\theta} \, e^{i k r \cos{\theta}} = \frac1{i k r} \left (e^{i k r} - e^{-i k r} \right ) = \frac{2 \sin{k r}}{k r}$$

Note that the integral over $\theta$ is not zero; the OP's mistake is likely in not changing the sign of the cosine in the limits.

So we have

$$F(k) = \frac{4 \pi}{k} \int_0^{\infty} dr \, e^{-a r} \sin{k r} = \frac{4 \pi}{a^2+k^2}$$

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to check my math there. As "a" goes to INF what is the limit of this?

Comment: Wait a second, the limit I had was -pi/2 to pi/2. you have 0 to pi. why the difference?

Comment: @JacksonHart: the 0 to $\pi$ limits are used with the sine factor to define the spherical coordinate system you want to use.  For your limits you would use a cosine rather than a sine.

Comment: Could you clarify the end of post? Is the final thing the answer? Or is just the radial component? It is hard to follow for me

Comment: @JacksonHart: final thing is the answer.  I skipped the steps because I felt it was not the point of the question.

Comment: You are right, I follow it now. Just had to work it out. I'll mark it as correct once I've worked through it. Also would the limit as a -> INF just be 0?

Comment: Also, where did the "i" go?

Comment: @JacksonHart: what "i"?  And yes, that limit is zero.

Comment: 1/ikr: the i disappears

Comment: If that is the case, was the "i" forgotton in the top-answer of this post?

Comment: @JacksonHart: huh?

Comment: sorry: this post :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388214/question-about-eulers-formula

Comment: @JacksonHart: no, the definition of cosine has no such "i" in front.

Comment: in the top answer, sin(ax) was defined how you have it but without the i

Comment: there is a discrepancy, you define sin(kr) as i*2*exp but in other post sin(ax) is defined as exp/2

Comment: I meant $i 2 \sin{k r} = (e^{i k r}-e^{-i k r})$.  sine has a factor of $i$.  There is no way around that.  If you are doing FT's, you should know that.  And I am done here.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. It is still not clear the final integral with regards to what method you used to solve an exp*sin but anyways, thanks for the help